# Why does the content moves down twice after the keyboard is dismissed in SwiftUI Form?

Tags: swift, swiftui, keyboard, ios16

When I tap on the TextField within a **Form**, the content appropriately **shifts upward** to accommodate the keyboard, as anticipated. However, upon **dismissing** the keyboard, the content doesn't return to its original position in a single smooth transition. Instead, it **moves down in two distinct steps**, which is not the desired behavior and seems unusual. Contrastingly, when using a **ScrollView** in place of a Form, this issue does not occur: the content shifts down just once and returns precisely to its initial position, as it should after the keyboard is dismissed. I am looking for a solution to ensure that within a Form, the content moves back down only once to its exact original position when the keyboard is dismissed.

IOS version: 16.0
My code:

```
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            ForEach(0 ..< 40, id: \.self) { index in
                TextField("input\(index + 1)", text: $inputs[index])
            }
        }
    }
```

Video link:(https://imgur.com/a/UAV55T5)

I am expecting the content to adjust smoothly and return to its initial position without any unwanted movements.

Comment: You should use `inputs` directly instead of half-open range here. And the animation often look bad on simulator, did you try on a real device?

Comment: I can reproduce this and this is most likely a bug in `Form`. And using `ScrollView` does resolve the issue. Can't you use `ScrollView` instead?

Comment: @son The same goes for real devices(iphone 12 mini).

Comment: @Aswath I need the default styles provided by the `Form`, do you know of any workarounds to address this issue with the `Form`?